# Page Transition Animation in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, ionic2, ionic3

I have simple tabs template Ionic 3 application in which, I am switching between the tabs whenever user swipes on view based on left or right I am switching between Tabs and All working fine accept there is no Animation effects when Page transition happens from tapping the tabs or from swiping the screen.

I am getting the Animation for page pushing and popping

```
this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage, {
    animation: true, direction: 'forward'
});
```

but not for selecting Tabs

```
this.navCtrl.parent.select(2,{
    animation: true, direction: 'forward'
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's currently not possible with Ionic, but you can use [this amazing plugin](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs) to achieve something like this:

[image]

In order to install it, just run

```
npm i --save ionic2-super-tabs
```

And then import `SuperTabsModule.forRoot()` in your app's main module

```
import { SuperTabsModule } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
      ...
      SuperTabsModule.forRoot()
      ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now everything is ready, so in your view you can do something like this:

```
<super-tabs>
  <super-tab [root]="page1" title="First page" icon="home"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="page2" title="Second page" icon="pin"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="page3" title="Third page" icon="heart"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

Comment: Its not worked for me. I have follow the steps you mentioned. Tabs are shown but pages are not loaded and swipe also not working. I am using Ionic 2

Comment: @AkshayDeshmukh please check the documentation of the GitHub repo, or create a new GitHub issue if you found any issues. It should work properly because several developers are using it in their projects (including me).

Comment: @sebaferreras, yes i follow all the steps, but i dont understand where i am wrong. Here is my git link 'https://github.com/akshayDeshmukh105/superTabDemo.git'. Can you tell me what is missed in it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

**Late answer** but may be useful for future users. You can achieve transition animation by this code. This question title & description is different. So I'm posting answer for title

```
goTo(page, params) {  //params are optional leave blank {} if you are not sending data
    this.navCtrl.push(page, { params: params }, { animate: true, animation: 'transition', duration: 500, direction: 'forward' });
}

goBack(){
    this.navCtrl.pop({animate:true,animation:'transition',duration:500,direction:'back'});
}
```

**Note**- If you are `BackButton` in `Navbar` do this

```
import {ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Navbar } from 'ionic-angular';  

//create global variable
@ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;

//inside ionViewDidLoad override back button
ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProductPage');
this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e: UIEvent) => {
        // todo something
        console.log("Back Back");
        this.navCtrl.pop({animate:true,animation:'transition',duration:500,direction:'back'});
    }
}
```

> If you need other animations you can [Follow this Article](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-native-page-transitions/) which is good implementation of ionic-native transition but these only works on device not browser